# Manipulating String Values within an Object using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

My goal is to take two objects (created by importing CSVs) that have host names and compare one list to the other and show what's missing from each.

Before I can do the comparison I need to manipulate the host names stored within the object(s). The first step is to use regular expressions to remove (`-replace`) unnecessary text and then set all host names to lowercase (`ToLower()`).

I'm not very proficient with modifying existing objects and keeping them "intact", so I'm hoping someone could help me with this.

Here's an example of the data stored within the CSV. The header is on line 7 and each line of data is stored like:

```
   ...
 7 "name","IP","OSType"
 8 "WCSMserver.com","10.10.10.10","OSX"
 9 "SERVER2.com","11.11.11.11","Windows"
10 "windowsserver @ SERVER2.com","11.11.11.13","Windows"
11 "winner.comSERVER2.com","11.11.11.12","Windows"
   ...
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do so far (just replacing the name property values):

```cs
function ReadExcelReport() {
  $global:ConvertedQReportTest = $PSScriptRoot + "\" + "AllSources.csv"
  $global:QReportObject = Get-Content -Path $global:ConvertedQReportTest |
                          Select-Object -Skip 7 |
                          ConvertFrom-Csv
}

ReadExcelReport

$global:QReportObject.name = $global:QReportObject.name | ForEach-Object {
    @($global:QReportObject.name)

    $_ -replace 'WCSM \- ' `
       -replace '.*?@ '`
       -replace '.*?@'`
       -replace '.*?\:\:.*?'`
       -replace '\.cooper\.winner\.com'`
       -replace '\.winner\.com'
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does something not work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: It the form above it does not work and I receive the following error "The property 'name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.". However, if I use: "$NewObject = $global:QRadarReportObject.name | ForEach-Object{ ..." it will replace the values, but it creates an entirely new object and that's not what I am trying to do.

Comment: `$global:QReportObject.name =` doesn't do what you expect. This shorthand syntax is to *get* `name` property from all elements from  `QReportObject` array. To assign each element's property you need to iterate the elements individually: `foreach ($o in QReportObject) { $o.name = $o.name -replace .....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `$global:QReportObject.name | ForEach-Object` you loop the names of the objects and not the objects.

I've simplified your script a bit (for readability):

```
$csv = @"
"name"
"WCSMserver-remove this-com"
"SERVER2.com","11.11.11.11"
"windowsserver-remove this-"
"winner.comSERVER2.com"
"@

$global:QReportObject = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv

$global:QReportObject | Out-Default

$global:QReportObject | ForEach-Object {
    $_.name = $_.name -replace '-remove this-'
    $_.name = $_.name.ToLower()
}

$global:QReportObject | Out-Default
```

This will output:

```
name                      
----                      
WCSMserver-remove this-com
SERVER2.com               
windowsserver-remove this-
winner.comSERVER2.com     



name                 
----                 
wcsmservercom        
server2.com          
windowsserver        
winner.comserver2.com
```